# c# entity framework, sql to classes

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

Table descriptions

Producer_Table as table: pro_id[int], pro_fname[varchar], pro_lname[varchar];

Artist_Table as table: pro_id[int], artist_id[int], artist_fname[varchar], artist_lname[varchar];

Song_table as table: artist_id[int], song_id[int], song_name[varchar], song_length[time]

C#
    using(Datacontext context = new Datacontext())

{

```
    Iqueryable<'Artist_Table> artist_query = context.Artist_Tables.where(aID =>     aId.artist_id == 8);
```

//Now say that I want to copy all of the data that the query returned and
   //keep the original data in place,
   //but add this data to a new Artist_Table object.

foreach(Artist_Table artItem in artist_query)

```
{ 
    //Everything's good here.
    Artist_Table artistObj = new Artist_Table();
    artistObj.artist_fname = "Dally";
    artistObj.artist_lname = "Winston";
```

//Now I'm looking to copy all of the Song_table data to this newly created entity.
    //so it will sort of be duplicated, but with different inique ID values.
         //..I did do another foreach(Song s in song_query), but it took way to long  .

```
    }  
}
```

Comment: Without seeing some code it is hard to tell. Who knows what approach you are using to execute this process?

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I'll put something together.  My dev machine is on a seperate network.

Comment: What do you mean by "takes much time"? Much time to write code or much time to execute?

Comment: Well, if I had to guess, based on the extensive code sample you have provided, I'd have to conclude that you are traversing the properties a few times, and not in parallel or pipeline mode. If copying data is all you need, why not consider SMO?

Comment: I'm sorry, I totaly messed up the original part of the question.  This just got ugly.  Kirill, I meant that I have to traverse each entity and make a new instance to write a copy of the original to the db with its own unique identifiers.

Comment: Darek, thanks for the suggestion.  Sorry about the limited description, but I think you guessed what I was asking.  I'll try SQL Management Objects.  I'll also try to recreate my original question and give you credit for the answer.  Thanks again.

Comment: Before you do that Chris ... Now that we can see more of your code, if you still insist on using EF, consider this: you do not have to add entities one by one. For example, You can add all the songs at once, than commit the artist.

Comment: Thanks Darek!  I will try to organize this a little better tomorrow and see if I can't get you involved again.  I'm not sure if I can add all songs at once, because they are still associated with the previous artist.  Then I will get an error.  I will try to provide more tomorrow.  I have made a mess out of this post anyway.  Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

Use SQL Management Objects if it helps. Depending on how much data you want to transfer, it might be a solution for you.

Comment: - 1. the OP is using a technology and states he has a problem. We don't know the details of his problem but the answer is not "use another technology" just for the sake of it.

Comment: True, no challenge here. This answer was posted when there was virtually no code to look at.